# Synchronization between TFS 2008 and TFS 2010

Tags: tfsintegrationplatform

I am in a situation where the corporation has just recently upgraded to TFS 2008. They have no intention of upgrading to TFS 2010 at this time. As a development group, we've moved to Visual Studio 2010 this week. As with any large corporation, we cannot get our own environment created to install TFS 2010. Steps on too many toes, and isn't corporate standard. Etc.

I want to take full advantage of the new testing features in relation to the new UI Testing and other features. This appears to require TFS 2010. So my "dream" is to do my daily work at the office and write tests, but at night, have my code synchronized with my TFS 2010 server at home and run automated builds with the full testing capabilities enabled.

So is there is best practice for this? I've read up on the Workspace theory and the binding issues that are involved and that sounds the biggest hurdle to overcome.

Possible Solution - Create two workspaces $/WorkProject and $/WorkProject-Mirror and use a custom application using FileSystemWatcher to kick off a job that synchronizes code changes and a custom rewrite of the bindings. Use job on work laptop and home machine to allow bi-directional binding.

Research to see if [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) will help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct the new testing UI (Test Manager 2010) requires TFS 2010, you are also correct that you can use the TFS Integration Platform between a TFS2008 & TFS2010 server. Then use test manager on the 2010 server.

All the above should be easy, the tough part will be the bindings in the solution file. I would suggest you have a second one created that points to your TFS2010 server so that you can open the correct solution file for the correct environment without stepping on your co-workers toes.

I think the two workspace route is overkill, it's just a solution file you need.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could use a read-only account to perform a [get](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx) from TFS2008 and then do a [check-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c327ca1z(v=VS.100).aspx) to your TFS2010 with a more-privileged account. I'm sure those two things and a little clever PowerShell scripting could get you what you're looking for.

I would encourage you to write a second utility to monitor that this script continues to work and to notify you if it detects a failure or something.

Comment: Wouldn't that only be one direction? Ideally I want bi-directional. It's also a disconnected environment. At work I'm on the corporate network, at home, I'm on the private network. There is no direct connection between the two.

Comment: Yes. If you have bi-directional synchronization, then you're going to have to deal with merge issues and I'm not sure how automated you want that. I didn't realize that you wanted bi-directional since you said you just wanted this for performing builds and doing testing with VS2010.